# discord says "Your message could not be delivered." when I try to write a message on a server I was invited to

Tags: discord

I'm having some difficulty sending messages to a server I was invited to. The message I get when I try to write anything is

> Your message could not be delivered. This is usually because you don't share a server with the recipient or the recipient is only accepting direct messages from friends. You can see the full list of reasons here: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060145013

one suggestion I heard was to restart discord but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Trying discord in a web browser worked.

Looks to me like web browser discord tends to be very up to date.. and sometimes once working in the web browser it works in the desktop program.

When I tried it in the web browser it then prompted me to read some stuff (the "server rules" maybe).

I clicked ok and then it was fine I could write in the server or I suppose message a moderator of the server i need be.

And if I go to the desktop discord program now it works I can write messages in rooms/channels on the server. I no longer get that message and am no longer prevented from writing messages on the server.